# MySQL: Combine the values of two different columns of two associated rows respectively

Tags: mysql, join, pivot

An example to demonstrate the problem:

```
ID: The primary key.

argID: A foreign key pointing to another table.

dependentID: A foreign key pointing to the field ID of the table itself.

dependentArgID: A foreign key pointing to the same table as argID.
```

I want to combine two associated rows (having the same dependentID) into one result row respectively, always selecting the date of the first and the number of the next row:

```
ID  argID   dependentID dependentArgID  date        number
1   1       2           2               2016-06-06  null
2   2       2           null            null        1
3   1       4           2               2016-06-07  null
4   2       4           null            null        2
...
```

Desired result:

```
argID   date        dependentArgID  number
1       2016-06-06  2               1
1       2016-06-07  2               2
...
```

**Problem in short form**: To rows with the same `dependentID` should be "merged" into one row with the `date` and the `number` (and optionally the `argID` and the `dependentArgID`) of these rows.

What I tried, is a self-join, but I do not get the right rows grouped:

NOT working correctly (and without the additional result fields):

```
SELECT `b`.`date`, `a`.`number`
FROM `table` `a` LEFT JOIN `table` `b` ON `a`.`argID` = `b`.`dependentArgID`
WHERE `a`.`argID` = 2
GROUP BY `a`.`dependentID`;
```

Comment: And the IDs are always sequential (incremental, and with no gaps)?

Comment: You can't count on that. The solution must be independent of any number sequences of IDs. The ID is an autoincrement value which may produce gaps

Comment: Why does argID 1 appear twice in the result set?

Comment: `argID` 1 belongs logically to `date` and `argID` 2 belongs to `number`. (the `argID` is the ID of a key saved in another table that belongs to a `date` or `number` value). But you may ignore `argID` and `dependentArgID` in relation to the result set. The important fields in the desired result set are the correctly "grouped" `date` and `number` fields (Note: `date` and `number` with the same `dependentID` belong to each other).

Comment: maybe a `UNION` is the solution. I'll check that...

Comment: From the comments, the question seems more complex than the data set suggests. Consider providing a properly representative data set as a set of CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH a desired result. None of the capitlizations above are accidental.

Comment: But the problem itself is simple - in contrast to the way to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first try (see my post) pointed to the right direction.

The correct solution is:

```
SELECT `b`.`argID`, `b`.`date`, `b`.`dependentArgID`, `a`.`number`
FROM `table` `a`
CROSS JOIN `table` `b`
ON `a`.`ID` = `b`.`dependentID`
WHERE `a`.`argID` = 2 AND `b`.`date` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `a`.`dependentID`;
```

Thanks to all helpers for the brain stimulation.

Comment: you rely on the ID in your answer (what is not what i want). and you are using a subquery. what is more efficient must be verified.